# 1x fast guard relay or 3x smaller middlerelays- what’s better for the network?

Tags: relays, network-health, fast-relays

As I am running 6 relays in different sizes at the moment I asked myself what is better for the Tor network in general:

- 1x fast guard relay with 100 Mbits unlimited traffic
- 3x smaller middlerelays that i run with 3 Mbits actually because they have a limit of 2 TB/month

Costs for both available options are the same!
On the one hand a fast relay can act as guard and as a middle relay and can have more connections running at the same time.
But on the other hand many small relays can keep tracking a hard job because there are more possible servers to watch on.

Is one of the options preferred by the Tor network creators? For me its hard to decide whats better for the whole network.

Comment: If your small relay has transfer limit per month, then set this limit in tor relay configuration and do not cap bandwidth to 3 mbit. After monthly limit is reached, relay will sleep for rest of month. This is much better for network.

Comment: Ok, i will do so. But if more bandwidth is prefered by the network in generall a 100 Mbits relay running the whole month will be better then 3 relays running for just a part of the month, right?

Comment: As said, price of both options is the same. I just need to decide what option i will keep running in the future.

Comment: I use tor almost exclusively for hidden services. For mine use is better to have more middle relays since I need 5 of them to build circuit to hidden service.